# How to fix "A debugging check in this application failed" codeblocks?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb

I was working on a project in Codeblocks, but at one point when I wanted to Run it, the Debug window just remained empty.I thought that it was just an infinite thing, but while I was looking at it, it showed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4DM1.png), sayng that "A debugging check in this application failed".If I pressed "Continue" it would let me go and it would give me the result, but when I tried to debug the code, it said the same thing, and afterwards it wouldn't let me debug.
Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream fin("forta.in");
ofstream fout("forta.out");
int main()
{
    int p,n,maxx=0;
    long long x,minn=2000000000;
    fin>>p>>n;
    if(p==1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            fin>>x;
            long long divt=1,p,cx=x,m=0;
            long long frp[x+1], prim[x+1];
            frp[0]=0;
            frp[1]=0;
            for(int i=2; i<=x; i++)
                frp[i]=1;
            for(int i=2; i<=x; i++)
            {
                if(frp[i]==1)
                {
                    prim[m++] =i; ///stochez nr prime
                    for(int j=i+i; j<=x; j=j+i)
                        frp[j]=0;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<m ; i++) ///  sirul de nr prime
            {
                p=0;

                while(x%prim[i]==0)
                {
                    p++;
                    x=x/prim[i];
                }
                divt=divt*(p+1);

            }
            if(divt>maxx)
            {
                maxx=divt;
                minn=cx;
            }
            else if(divt==maxx)
            {
                if(cx<minn)
                    minn=cx;
            }
        }
        fout<<minn;
    }
    if(p==2)
    {
        int fr[20000]= {0}, maxx=0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            fin>>x;
            long long divt=1,p,cx=x,m=0;
            long long frp[x+1], prim[x+1];
            frp[0]=0;
            frp[1]=0;
            for(int i=2; i<=x; i++)
                frp[i]=1;
            for(int i=2; i<=x; i++)
            {
                if(frp[i]==1)
                {
                    prim[++m] =i; ///stochez nr prime
                    for(int j=i+i; j<=x; j=j+i)
                        frp[j]=0;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<m ; i++) ///  sirul de nr prime
            {
                p=0;

                while(x%prim[i]==0)
                {
                    p++;
                    x=x/prim[i];
                }
                divt=divt*(p+1);

            }
            fr[divt]++; /// frecventa pe nr de div
            if(maxx<fr[divt])
                maxx=fr[divt];
        }
        fout<<maxx;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It all goes well until "fout<<minn;"(line 54)
I wonder what caused that error and how to fix it.

P.S.
Here is the debug log:

```
    Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
    Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
    Selecting target: 
    Debug
    Adding source dir: C:\Users\Tudor\CodeBlocks\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta\
    Adding source dir: C:\Users\Tudor\CodeBlocks\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta\
    Adding file: C:\Users\Tudor\CodeBlocks\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta\bin\Debug\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta.exe
    Changing directory to: C:/Users/TT/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta/.
    Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\TT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\TT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
    
    [debug]Command-line: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Users/TT/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta/bin/Debug/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta.exe
    [debug]Working dir : C:\Users\TT\CodeBlocks\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta
    
    Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Users/TT/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta/bin/Debug/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta.exe
    done
    
    [debug]Reading symbols from C:/Users/TT/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta/bin/Debug/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta.exe...
    [debug]done.
    [debug](gdb) 
    [debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:
    
    Setting breakpoints
    
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> show version
    [debug]GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
    [debug]Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    [debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    [debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    [debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    [debug]and "show warranty" for details.
    [debug]This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
    [debug]Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
    [debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    [debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
    [debug]Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    [debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
    [debug]For help, type "help".
    [debug]Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set confirm off
    
    Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
    
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set width 0
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set height 0
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set breakpoint pending on
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set print asm-demangle on
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set unwindonsignal on
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set print elements 200
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set new-console on
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> set disassembly-flavor att
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> catch throw
    [debug]Catchpoint 1 (throw)
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> directory C:/Users/TT/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta/
    [debug]Source directories searched: C:/Users/Tudor/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta;$cdir;$cwd
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> break "C:/Users/TT/CodeBlocks/OJI_2020_A6-A_forta/main2.cpp:54"
    [debug]Breakpoint 2 at 0x401925: file C:\Users\TT\CodeBlocks\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta\main2.cpp, line 54.
    [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
    [debug]> run
    [debug]Starting program: C:\Users\TT\CodeBlocks\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta\bin\Debug\OJI_2020_A6-A_forta.exe 

Child process PID: 6060

[debug][New Thread 6060.0x1624]
```

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you have an "array" whose size is set at run-time then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: I was working  info contest subjects

Comment: Since the error dialog is from `wxWidgets`, it's either a bug in there or in CodeBlocks.